# How do I reduce the area of the bar graph and increase that of the text in Grafana? (make labels more readable)

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

I have long strings as labels which is the full identifier of each deployment. How do I increase the area that the strings occupy and reduce the area for the bar graphs in Grafana.

 After many attempts, this is the closest that I have come to displaying label strings in a way that is readable. Ideally a table would also  be nice, but I was unable to show a table in which the labels form a column (it always took the row)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change that size. I would rather focus how to make labels shorter. (I would say that "max_Sum/" is not necessary there)

IMHO: the best option is to have a table panel for this - yes, you wasn't not able to achieve it, but you only need right query, result format + transformation eventually.